# Trigger a Workflow From Another Workflow

Tags: triggers, workflow, azure-logic-apps

I have a Logic App in Azure and that Logic App has 2 workflows in it.
I am trying to trigger the 2nd Workflow from the 1st Workflow.
How do I do that, please?

Please do NOT just post a URL with a document, if I wanted that I would Google it myself, as indeed I have already. I just need some simple explanation as to how to trigger 1 workflow from another IN THE SAME Logic App.

Thank you very much!

Have added "Invoke A Workflow From This Workflow App" to the end of the 1st workflow, and have specified the workflow that I want to trigger.
Received message that I need to add a "Request Trigger" instead of a "Recurrence Trigger". I have no idea what to do after that point, or how to construct the JSON to allow for this.

Comment: This doesn’t make complete sense … “how to trigger 1 workflow from another IN THE SAME Logic App.” … what do you mean by “the same”? Is this LogicApps standard or consumption? To trigger another LogicApp, the trigger needs to be “receive a HTTP request”

Comment: Also, it’s our perogative to provide links to documentation. That’s what documentation is for. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Hi, 1st comment: it makes perfect sense. I have 2 workflows, these workflows are in the same logic app. I want to execute 1 workflow from the other. I don't really see what's confusing about that, tbh. 2nd comment: What I didn't want was simply a post with a URL in it, because not only is that - (imho) - unhelpful, but it's kinda lazy as well. INCLUDING a URL in a helpful answer is an entirely different thing, though. Doesn't matter anyway as I've figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

I have two workflows- workflow1 and workflow2 and I am invoking workflow2 from workflow1 in the following way,

If you have a Recurrence trigger in workflow2 then you will get below error, instead you need to use HTTP trigger in your secondary workflow but you can have Recurrence trigger in your primary workflow if you want.

[image]

> I have no idea what to do after that point, or how to construct the JSON to allow for this.

Click on **Use sample payload to generate schema**

[image]

[image]

[image]

**workflow2-**

[image]

**workflow1-**

[image]

**Output-**

[image]